# How do set select element array index when it is in array and bind to blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of select dom and input textbox . On  blur event of input(of perticular index) want to set the element in select dom value of same index.

My bind is working but after each blur event for different input box it is retiurning 0.

I am not able to set the select value i.e. (drop down)as per given index

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kamleshahire/BwMnw/)

My code is following.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var i =1;
    $('#addme').on('click', function(){

        var  test = '<tr class="employee"><td><input type="text" id="emp_id['+i+']" /></td><td><select id="emp_name['+i+']" '
        test += '<option value="-1" >Please Select </option><option value="e0001" >James Smith</option><option value="e0002" >Roger Sm</option>'  
        test +='<option value="e0003" >Elina Lobo</option></select></td></tr>'   
         
        $('#addme').after(test);
        i++;
    });

    $(".employee input").live('blur',function(){
        var inputIndex = $(this).index();
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        alert("Input Index is :" +  inputIndex + ' and value is ' + inputValue);

        $('#emp_name[inputIndex]').each(function(){
            if(this.value == inputValue){
                $('#emp_name[inputIndex]').val($(this).val()); 
                    return false;
            }
            alert("Please iput valid value");
            $('#emp_name[inputIndex]').val('-1');
        });
    });
});
    </script>
    <table />
    <tr class="employee">
        <td><input class="employee" type="text" id="emp_id[0]" /></td>
        <td><select id="emp_name[0]" name="emp_name">
            <option value="-1" >Please Select </option>
            <option value="e0001" >James Smith</option>         
            <option value="e0002" >Roger Sm</option>
            <option value="e0003" >Elina Lobo</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr> 

    <input type="button" id="addme" value="ADD ME"/> 

  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to **delegate the events** as you are adding the elements dynamically on the click of the button..

So `$(".employee input").live('blur',function(){`

should look something like this

```
$(staticContainer).on('blur',".employee input", function(){
```

**staticContainer** is the element that is already in the DOM when the elements are bound with the element.

Closer the container better the performance.

**Also you have multiple issues with your code..**

It is a better idea to append the rows to the table, so that the selector returns the right element inside the table.

```
$('#addme').after(test);
```

Supposed to be

```
$('table').append(test);
```

Next this selector does not replace the index value

```
$('#emp_name[inputIndex]')
```

supposed to be

```
$('#emp_name[' + inputIndex + ']')
```

Lastly the way you are accessing the indexes is completely wrong.

You are trying to get the current input with respective to the other elements . So

```
var inputIndex = $(this).index();
```

supposed to look like

`var inputIndex = $('input').index(this);` // which will give the right value.

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/BwMnw/1/)**

Comment: I have tried using like this  <div id='employee'> <td><input  type="text" id="emp_id[0]" /></td> but no use

Answer (score 0):

First,jQuery .Index() means find the index of e's all siblings,not the index of the selector field,if you want to do so,you need a selector parameter.
So

`var inputIndex = $(this).index();`

should change to

`var inputIndex = $(this).index(".employee input");`

then your index part will work fine.

Second,I actually don't understand your blur event code part.You said you want to set the same index of select dom,why you compare the value?And you use the jQuery attribute selector and I didn't see any match element.I guess you try to select all select doms,and you try to alert on loop?I don't think it's a good idea.

I think you should rebuild this part,it has no logic and very hard to read now.